# Достать данные из массива и добавить их в таблицу - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

```js
$("#reg").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php', //Файл в который отсылаем данные
    type: "POST", // Как передаем POST or GET
    success: function(data) {
      $('#info').text(data);
      var res = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info"></div>
<!-- Form: the action="javascript:insert()"calls the javascript function "insert" into ajax_framework.js -->
<button id="reg" value="Insert"> dff</button>
```

Массив такого вида

```
{"0":"1","ID":"1","1":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","Date":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","2":"Student1","Name":"Student1","3":"student1@stud.com","Email":"student1@stud.com","4":"89123456789","Phone":"89123456789","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f","Comment":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}
```

Подскажите как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то примерно так:

```js
$("#reg").click(function() {
  var $table = $('#my_table'),
    $table_head = $table.find('thead'),
    $table_body = $table.find('tbody');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php', //Файл в который отсылаем данные
    type: "POST", // Как передаем POST or GET
    success: function(data) {
      $('#info').text(data);
      var res = JSON.parse(data)

      // Перебираем массив
      res.forEach(function(value) {
        // Добавляем строку в таблицу
        var $table_tr = $table_body.append('<tr></tr>')

        for (var key in value) {
          if (Number(key) !== parseFloat(key)) {
            // Создаём заголовки, которых нет
            if (!$table.find('thead td:contains("' + key + '")').length) $table_head.append('<td>' + key + '</td>');

            // Добавляем данные в строку
            $table_tr.append('<td>' + value[key] + '</td>')
          };
        };
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info"></div>
<!-- Form: the action="javascript:insert()"calls the javascript function "insert" into ajax_framework.js -->
<button id="reg" value="Insert"> dff</button>

<table id="my_table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ещё можно генерировать таблицу прямо на серверной части, но это уже совсем другая история...

Пример:

```js
// Переменная для примера
var res = [{"0":"1","ID":"1","1":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","Date":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","2":"Student1","Name":"Student1","3":"student1@stud.com","Email":"student1@stud.com","4":"89123456789","Phone":"89123456789","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f","Comment":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}, {"0":"2","ID":"2","1":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","Date":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","2":"Student2","Name":"Student2","3":"student1@stud.com","Email":"student2@stud.com","4":"89123456789","Phone":"89864256789","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f","Comment":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}];

$("#reg").click(function() {
  var $table = $('#my_table'),
      $table_head = $table.find('thead'),
      $table_body = $table.find('tbody');
  
  // Перебираем массив
  res.forEach(function (value) {
    // Добавляем строку в таблицу
    var $table_tr = $table_body.append('<tr></tr>')
    
    for(var key in value) {
      if (Number(key) !== parseFloat(key)) {
        // Создаём заголовки, которых нет
        if (!$table.find('thead td:contains("' + key + '")').length) $table_head.append('<td>' + key + '</td>');
        
        // Добавляем данные в строку
        $table_tr.append('<td>' + value[key] + '</td>')
      };
    };
  });
      
  /*$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php', //Файл в который отсылаем данные
    type: "POST", // Как передаем POST or GET
    success: function(data) {
      $('#info').text(data);
      var res = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(data);
    }
  });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info"></div>
<!-- Form: the action="javascript:insert()"calls the javascript function "insert" into ajax_framework.js -->
<button id="reg" value="Insert"> dff</button>

<table id="my_table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Не пойму, почему ругается на res.forEach?

Comment: @Сергей, а какие данные у вас выходят в `res`?

Comment: @Сергей, попробуйте так https://jsfiddle.net/5r00z5vg/1/